# How to detect a structural break in panel data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, panel-data, structural-change

I have the following problem with determining whether there is a general structural break in my panel data. Suppose we have 100 countries producing rice from 2000 to 2010. Now for a certain country I can detect a structural break almost automatically in an endogenous manner. However, this would produce structural breaking dates for that certain country.

Now, I understand that the structural breaking dates could be different for every country.
**My question is how do I roll up the structural breaks per country to detect structural breaks in my entire panel data?** In short, how do I deal with panel data to detect whether there are structural breaks in general (for the 100 countries).

I am currently trying to conduct this research in R if it matters at all.

In addition, I do not know whether a structural break exists and where the structural breaks should be. So I think a Chow test would not be the best solution.

Comment: Can you expand on the type of structural break you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to detect structural breaks in my panel data. Is there a way to do a chow test or some automatic test if we do not know the number of structural breaks and where the structural breaks are?

Comment: there are different types of structural breaks, such as structural breaks on the coefficients, or on the noise. A brute-force approach to this would be to make a large list (or nested loops) with all the combinations of breaks you would want to consider, and calculate that out-of-sample performance for each one of those models, and then go with the one with the best performance (if it's significantly better than the one without structural breaks